# Two Codebases, composer in both causing issues with redeclaring functions

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two codebases, one running as the primary web app, the other as the old code with legacy pages.  Both codebases have their own composer installations, and that is where the problem occurs.  When the first codebase has to call the second one, it is just a `require secondApp`.  Both apps have, in requirements for other libraries, pake.  The problem comes that Pake has a `pake_autoloader` function and the second one is noticing that the first already declared it, and throws an exception saying I cannot redeclare it.  Both of these apps load Pake as a requirement for other libs.  How do I get around the redeclaring issue?

Answer (score 0):

Move both applications into one, and have only one composer.json file. Because by executing code of the "other" application, this really is only one big application.

A different idea would be to clearly seperate the two and only communicate via a defined interface, like making HTTP calls to the other application and using what's being returned.